# Need to sanitize body of ResponseEntity in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, xss, sanitization

I am running a Java 8, Tomcat, DynamoDB stack. I have this method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{var:.*}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response mirrorRest(@Context UriInfo info, @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context HttpEntity entity,
                               @PathParam(value = "var") String var) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI("https", server, null, null);
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uri);
    builder.path(var);
    for(String key : info.getQueryParameters().keySet()){
        if(!key.equals("key")){
            String queryParam = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(info.getQueryParameters().get(key).get(0));
            builder.query(key+ "=" + queryParam);
        }
    }
    builder.query("key="+API_KEY);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    try {    
        ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        Object responseBody = response.getBody();

        return Response.ok(response.getBody()).build();
    } catch(HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        return Response.status(e.getStatusCode().value()).entity(e.getResponseBodyAsString()).build();
    }
}
```

At one point I am reading from `springframework.http.HttpEntity`, creating a `ResponseEntity`. However, I want to sanitize the body before I output it to avoid XSS. This is what I haven't figured out how to do, because the `getBody()` will return an `Object`:

```
Object responseBody = response.getBody();
```

Any ideas on how to handle this `Object` to ensure that it is sanitized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just this way

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), 
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

String responseBody = response.getBody();
```

ResponseBody is a container for the response body with possible type parametrization.

If you expect some JSON serializable content it's better to parametrize `ResponseEntity` with the proper class to which this JSON could be deserialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code

```
 try {    
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    String responseBody = response.getBody();

    return Response.ok(response.getBody()).build();
} catch(HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    return Response.status(e.getStatusCode().value()).entity(e.getResponseBodyAsString()).build();
}
```

Now your getBody() will return String.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!